# Remove sticky navbar while scrolling down using UIKit 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, uikit

I'm using the UIKit CSS framework. I'm trying to hide a sticky navbar. I want to use a sticky navbar in one page and the same navbar to remove sticky in another page navbar section.

I tried the following UIKit code for this purpose but I've been unable to do so. Please give me some suggestions.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div uk-sticky="sel-target: .uk-navbar-container; cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky; bottom: #transparent-sticky-navbar">
  <nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar style="position: relative; z-index: 980;">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">
      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent</a>
          <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
              <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="uk-container "> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit doloremque magnam, officia quaerat accusantium, quia cupiditate nulla ratione quos quis esse! Delectus blanditiis dignissimos sequi repellat debitis itaque iure quam tenetur assumenda
  nisi repellendus magni, dolore odit laborum officia ducimus error, quod, voluptatem nostrum perspiciatis? Asperiores sit, do asperiores consequuntur veniam eius quasi labore perspiciatis, natus dolor nam atque. Cupiditate quasi, sequi dolores impedit
  mollitia vitae modi et saepe architecto nisi rerum dicta est praesentium cumque reprehenderit autem enies similique animi eligendi porro qui voluptatibus. Repudiandae hic placeat labore blanditiis adipisci consectetur molestiae, vel possimus ex deleniti
  iure. Quasi accusamus corporis, fugit incidunt nisi repellendus quo similique est provident tenetur, aperiam ex a. Provident quas, aliquam fugit aut nisi deleniti consequuntur numquam excepturi quae consequatur. Quas molestias, natus sunt voluptate
  hic eum cumque.labore blanditiis adipisci consectetur molestiae, vel possimus ex deleniti iure. Quasi accusamus corporis, fugit incidunt nisi repellendus quo similique est provident tenetur, aperiam ex a. Provident quas, aliquam fugit aut nisi deleniti
  consequuntur numquam excepturi quae consequatur. Quas molestias, natus sunt voluptate hic eum cumque </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide sticky navbar when you scroll the page ?

Answer (score 1):

The portion of code you want to remove from the second page is this:

`uk-sticky="sel-target: .uk-navbar-container; cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky; bottom: #transparent-sticky-navbar"`

I would some server side logic to workout whether or not the page should include this line before sending it to the user's browser.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div >
  <nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar style="position: relative; z-index: 980;">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">
      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent</a>
          <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
              <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="uk-container "> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit doloremque magnam, officia quaerat accusantium, quia cupiditate nulla ratione quos quis esse! Delectus blanditiis dignissimos sequi repellat debitis itaque iure quam tenetur assumenda
  nisi repellendus magni, dolore odit laborum officia ducimus error, quod, voluptatem nostrum perspiciatis? Asperiores sit, do asperiores consequuntur veniam eius quasi labore perspiciatis, natus dolor nam atque. Cupiditate quasi, sequi dolores impedit
  mollitia vitae modi et saepe architecto nisi rerum dicta est praesentium cumque reprehenderit autem enies similique animi eligendi porro qui voluptatibus. Repudiandae hic placeat labore blanditiis adipisci consectetur molestiae, vel possimus ex deleniti
  iure. Quasi accusamus corporis, fugit incidunt nisi repellendus quo similique est provident tenetur, aperiam ex a. Provident quas, aliquam fugit aut nisi deleniti consequuntur numquam excepturi quae consequatur. Quas molestias, natus sunt voluptate
  hic eum cumque.labore blanditiis adipisci consectetur molestiae, vel possimus ex deleniti iure. Quasi accusamus corporis, fugit incidunt nisi repellendus quo similique est provident tenetur, aperiam ex a. Provident quas, aliquam fugit aut nisi deleniti
  consequuntur numquam excepturi quae consequatur. Quas molestias, natus sunt voluptate hic eum cumque </div>
```